# Getting-started: Setup Database for Node.js

Tags: javascript, database, node.js

I am new to node.js but am excited to try it out. I am using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) as a web framework, and [Jade](http://jade-lang.com) as a template engine. Both were easy to get setup following [this tutorial](http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/11434722) from [Node Camp](http://camp.nodejs.org/).

However the one problem I am finding is **I can't find a simple tutorial for getting a DB set up**. I am trying to build a basic chat application (store session and message).

**Does anyone know of a good tutorial?**

This other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750673/node-js-database) talks about dbs to use- but as this is very different from the Django/MySQL world I've been in, I want to make sure I understand what is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: I hate to be the one to say this, but I think a framework is a poor teacher of a programming language.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**I assume you have [npm](https://github.com/isaacs/npm) installed the correct way using one of these [snippets](https://gist.github.com/579814)(I used the top one).**

### Redis

I would use redis as a database. For one it is really [fast](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks), persistent. You need to install it, but that is really easy.

```
make
```

### Redis-cli

Next you should play with redis yourself. I would advice you to look at this excellent tutorial by [Simon Willison](http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/). He and I also advice you to just play with the `redis-cli` to get a feeling of the database.

### Redis client

Finally you need to install a redis client. I would advise you to use mranney's [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) because I think it is the fastest and most actively developed client.

**Installation**

```
npm install hiredis redis
```

**Simple example, included as example.js:**

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.set("string key", "string val", redis.print);
client.hset("hash key", "hashtest 1", "some value", redis.print);
client.hset(["hash key", "hashtest 2", "some other value"], redis.print);
client.hkeys("hash key", function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies.length + " replies:");
    replies.forEach(function (reply, i) {
        console.log("    " + i + ": " + reply);
    });
    client.quit();
});
```

### Storing sessions in database

Also the author of express has created a library to handle your [sessions](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) using redis.

**Installation:**

```
npm install connect-redis
```

**Example:**

```
var connect = require('connect')
      , RedisStore = require('connect-redis');

connect.createServer(
  connect.cookieDecoder(),
  // 5 minutes
  connect.session({ store: new RedisStore({ maxAge: 300000 }) })
);
```

### Storing messages in database

I think I would use a [sorted set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) for this. Store the messages using `ZADD` and retrieve them using `ZRANK`, `ZRANGEBYSCORE`.

### Socket.io

Finally if you are trying to create a simple chat I would advise you to have a look at socket.io.

> socket.io aims to make realtime apps
>   possible in every browser and mobile
>   device, blurring the differences
>   between the different transport
>   mechanisms.

I also created a chat using socket.io which I posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441798/how-to-use-redis-publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-by-event-driven/4446424#4446424). Adding persistence + authentication should be a breeze.

Answer (score 4):

Express authentication using Redis for session store and Couchdb for database using coffeescript..

Check this gist: https://gist.github.com/652819

I use this template for most of my projects. You can implement a similar mongodb version of it too using:

node-mongodb-native by christkv : https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native, or

mongoose : https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose, or

amark's mongous: https://github.com/amark/mongous

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the NodeCamp tutorial you mention there is another NodeCamp [tutorial](http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/11435693) given by Matt Ranney the aforementioned author of the redis node library. It goes into a wee bit more depth.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but in case anyone else stumbles upon it, I created a tutorial using most of the OP's components, especially the connection to the database. It does have some added complexity with the use of Backbone.js, but it is all in good fun!

http://fzysqr.com/2011/02/28/nodechat-js-using-node-js-backbone-js-socket-io-and-redis-to-make-a-real-time-chat-app/