# Best way to setup node.js database MongoDB/Redis?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redis, database

So here's my deal.

I'm using node on the express framework. The website i'm working on grabs scraped data and stores it for each user on the website. That data can then be displayed on the users page whenever they want to access it, so the data will be scraped, put in a database or storage, whatever i decide the best way to do it is, and then pulled back out for the user.

I'm trying to figure out what the best database setup would be. There will potentially be large amounts of data per user, especially over long periods of time. I've read some stuff about using redis to cache some data like the user login info and that basic stuff, and then using mongodb for the big data. But I don't know, i'm new to database stuff so I am open to some new teachings and some ideas from the masters.

What would you guys suggest I do? I want it to be fast and be able to handle multiple queries at the same time, but really, I have no idea what i'm talking about, so please help me.

Comment: As with all the 'somewhat broad question', this will probably be closed as not constructive. In case you don't get an answer, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750673/node-js-database?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478916/what-should-i-choose-mongodb-cassandra-redis-couchdb?rq=1)

Comment: The question is too vague. Regarding mongodb and redis see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696463/mongodb-with-redis/10721249#10721249 - If you are new to databases, my suggestion is to stick to mainstream relational databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, etc ...). NoSQL stores are for people who knows what they do (i.e. familiar with the CAP theorem, ACID/BASE definitions, typical storage data structures, etc ...).

Comment: Sorry guys, I have seen so many other questions similar to this and people always ask how it will be used in order to give a proper response. So that's what I did, if there's any other information you need to help me out, please let me know. I've already read the majority of popular posts about mongodb and redis, and still couldnt come to a conclusion, hence my post. And dont worry about me being new to databases, just point me in a direction and i'll take care of the rest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What would you guys suggest I do?

This really depends on the nature of your data, how you model your domain and how you want to persist it. I would first try to figure out the basic model and based on that choose the most suitable database system. Don't jump at quick conclusions around caching with redis when you don't even know if you will need it in the first place.

Suggestion might also depend on how much time you want to spend with database layer of your application. Some database systems provide more functionality than others depending on their concepts. If you are a beginner choose a single mainstream solution that is well documented with established community like MongoDB or MySQL that will cover all your needs from the beginning so that you won't end up managing multitude of systems.

Comment: @ribsies By nature of your data I meant how you structure it for your application. Depending on your domain and the problem you are solving, data can be stored in different structure, e.g. tabular, document, graph. Each structure provides it's own benefits and can be cached differently. You might want to cache your data to speed up some functionality of your application, but first you need to know which part of it would require caching so that you don't end up caching what doesn't even need to be cached.